# Domain classes to track Users and Games

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I'm trying to do something that seems so simple.  I have a User class, and I have a Game class that matches up two Users.  It's this simple:

```
class User {
    String username
    static hasMany = [games:Game]
}

class Game {
    User player1
    User player2
}
```

When I ran this, I got

```
Caused by GrailsDomainException: Property [games] in class [class User] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [user] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [games:'myprop']
```

So I did some digging and found [mappedBy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) and changed my code to:

```
class User {
    String username
    static hasMany = [games:Game]
    static mappedBy = [games:'gid']
}

class Game {
    User player1
    User player2
    static mapping = {
        id generator:'identity', name:'gid'
    }
}
```

Now I get

```
Non-existent mapping property [gid] specified for property [games] in class [class User]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd forgo what you started with and define the relationship as a simple many-to-many and control the biz logic of only 2 players per game elsewhere.

Comment: So you're saying keep the domain relatively simplistic by just saying that a `Game` `hasMany` `Users`, and then make sure it's exactly two _different_ Users within the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is probably what you want:

```
class User {

    static mappedBy = [player1Games: 'player1', player2Games: 'player2']

    static hasMany = [player1Games: Game, player2Games: Game]

    static belongsTo = Game
}

class Game {
    User player1
    User player2
}
```

Edit for new rules:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [ games: Game ]
    static belongsTo = Game
}

class Game {
    static hasMany = [ players: User ]
    static constraints = {
        players(maxSize: 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: To note, the only reason to do this is if you need/want to get games from a user object.

Comment: This works, thanks.  But there's one thing that still doesn't fit my scenario.  I created the player1 and player2 variables because I couldn't see a way around it.  (Apologies for that being misleading in my OP.)  I don't really want to have to distinguish between them.  There is no real distinction between the two players in a Game.  Is it possible for Game to have an array (size 2 would be ideal) of Users?  And for User to have many Games, rather than player1Games and player2Games?  I want to find all Games that a User is part of, and player1 or player2 is of no significance.

Comment: That's perfect.  Having said that, is there an easy fix to make scaffolding work here?